# How to unlock HP BIOS advanced option

Tags: linux, laptop, bios, hp-pavilion, intel-rst

My HP Pavilion laptop's BIOS is locked out by the manufacturer, preventing me from installing Linux. In the past,when I attempted to install Linux on my other laptop I had to turn off Intel RST and turn on AHCI mode

However, I am unable to perform the same action on my brand-new HP laptop since I do not have access to the Advanced BIOS function.

My question is:

1. Does Linux support intel RST now?
2. Is there anyway I can unlock laptop's BIOS settings? I tried with HP customer support but they said it is not possible.

Comment: Was it locked by HP (not likely) or your organization (school, business).  I think HP's answer confirms it was locked by someone else.

Comment: "Does Linux support intel RST now?" - No

Comment: "Is there anyway I can unlock laptop's BIOS settings?" - Provided the password used to lock the firmware settings, as for the reason HP said it was impossible, you likely indicated you don't have the password and they certainly did not lock it themselves so they didn't have the password.

Comment: HP does not allow advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of BIOS, one must **first set a password to access advanced features.** After setting it, boot and then shutdown. The next time BIOS is accessed, enter the password. (On some PC's, expect loud *beeping* until the password has been entered. Likely, this is a corporate "security" feature.)

If the password is already set, but has been forgotten, it may be [possible to reset it](https://www.4winkey.com/computer-help/how-to-reset-bios-password-on-hp-laptop.html).